# VS2017 with VSTS and GIT - How to disable autocommit on revert operation?

Tags: vb.net, git, visual-studio-2017, git-revert, team-explorer

Here it is the problem explanation.

## The Expectation

I want to **revert A SINGLE FILE** to a specific commit in a branch using GUI.

## The Environnement

I have a VB.NET Solution on Visual Studio 2017.
The *Solution* is under **Source Control** with a connected **Visual Studio Team Service** using **Git** as Repository.

## The Test Sample

1. Imagine to have 1 branch (e.g. *Dev*).
2. Imagine that *Dev* has 3 commit (e.g. *C1*, *C2*, *C3*; *C3* is the last one, and *C1* is the first one)
3. Imagine that you want to revert *C3* changes to file *A.vb*, so that is actual code looks like the same in *C2*
4. Imagine that only that file should be reverted, and no other *C3* affected files should turn back to *C2*

## What I'm trying to do

1. In **Solution Explorer**, select *A.vb* file, right click and select
   **Show History...**
2. In **History** window, select *C2*, right click and **Revert**

## The Problem

Doing the steps exposed above, if there's no conflict, it will revert the **ENTIRE** commit to the desired one (i.e. not only the selected file, but all the file changed in the commit)

## The Workaround

I know that there should be a lot of ways to do that with command line or through "View Commit Details" -> opne the *A.vb* file -> **save as..** in actual branch file area.

## The Idea

I hope that there should be an option, somewhere in VS2017 or Team Explorer, to disable the "**auto-commit on revert**" behaviour so that I'll be able to select only one file to stage it in the new commit.

I've no idea on how to do it... and if it's the right way too, obviously.

Comment: I tried to do this a few weeks ago and couldn't find any solution through Visual Studio. I don't think it's possible. Maybe someone has a solution for you (and me) though!